Define level order in data frame and the contrast coding in contr.sum
In R, when I use the contrast "contr.sum", the reference level is the grand average. However, is there a method to define the order of the coding? E.g. in the following example
  # Setup dataset:
  DF = data.frame(x1 = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0), 
                  x2 = c(10,25,10,10,25,25,25,10),
                  y  = c(1.233,1.182,1.459,5.053,1.254,4.832,3.889,5.389))
  # Define level order:
  DF$x1            = factor(DF$x1, levels=c(0,1))
  DF$x2            = factor(DF$x2, levels=c(10,25))
  # Display levels:
  DF$x2

  >> [1] 10 25 10 10 25 25 25 10
  >> Levels: 10 25

  # Display contrast coding:
  contrasts(DF$x2)

  >>    25
  >> 10  0
  >> 25  1

The levels in DF$x2 are how I defined them: first comes "10", then comes "25". Also the contrast coding is "natural": It uses 0 for the smaller value "10", and 1 for the larger value "25" -- I know, that R lost the "value" and uses my level definition instead.
Now, what happens if I change the reference value to the grand average:
  # Define contrast coding:
  contrasts(DF$x1) = contr.sum
  contrasts(DF$x2) = contr.sum

  # Display contrast coding:
  contrasts(DF$x2)

       [,1]
>> 10    1
>> 25   -1

The contrast coding uses +1 for "10" and -1 for "25". This is unnatural for me, and I need to check the contrast multiple times in every analysis. Hence, I would like to be able to swap the coding and use -1 for "10" and +1 for "25". Is this possible?
PS: I am aware that I could swap the levels when defining them, e.g.
DF$x2 = factor(DF$x2, levels=c(25, 10))

However, then the order of the levels in the data frame changes. While this is certainly the better option from my perspective, I wonder whether or not there is a simple method to achieve both: Using the level order c("10","25") in the data frame and using the contrast coding c(-1,1).
